# How to extract data from a HTML table?

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I recently downloaded HtmlAgilityPack but I haven't found any real instructions on how to use it.  I have attempted to piece together some code based on some various discussion board posts and other sources.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim document As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    document.LoadHtml("www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=GOOG")

    Dim tabletag = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='data']/tr[1]/td[2]")
End Sub
```

As you can see I am working with the HTML from `www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=GOOG`.

I am trying to extract the Beta value from this page.  This value is currently 1.04.

When I run the code above my immediate window shows this repeated 100 times:

```
1.04
&#36;243,156.41
328.59
--
--
Trading Report for (GOOG). A detailed report, including free correlated market analysis, and updates.
ValuEngine Detailed Valuation Report for GOOG
GOOGLE INC CL A (GOOG)  12-months forecast
GOOGLE INC CL A (GOOG)  2-weeks forecast
Google Inc: Business description, financial summary, 3yr and interim financials, key statistics/ratios and historical ratio analysis.
```

I only want the first number (1.04) returned.  What am I doing wrong?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use cookies and a proxy. The below works great for me. Let me know your thoughts:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web

Public Class Form1

    Public cookies As New CookieContainer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Dim wreq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=GOOG")

        wreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5"

        wreq.Method = "get"

        Dim prox As IWebProxy = wreq.Proxy

        prox.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials


        Dim document As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
        Dim web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb

        web.UseCookies = True
        web.PreRequest = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler(AddressOf onPreReq)

        wreq.CookieContainer = cookies

        Dim res As HttpWebResponse = wreq.GetResponse()


        document.Load(res.GetResponseStream, True)

        'just for testing:
        '   Dim tabletag = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")
        '  MsgBox(tabletag.Nodes.Count.ToString)

        'returns your field
        Dim tabletag2 = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='data']")
        MsgBox(tabletag2.InnerText)

    End Sub

    Private Function onPreReq(req As HttpWebRequest)

        req.CookieContainer = cookies
        Return True

    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: It works!  I have to finish integrating it into my program fully but this appears to be great!  Thanks!

Comment: What if I wanted to extract the 3rd row in that table?  (The 328.59)

Comment: I think this would do it:  Dim tabletag2 = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='overallRatios']//table[@class='dataTable']//tr[3]//td[2]")

Comment: Do I need to close anything before I run another URL?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. If I were you, I would make function that returns the values you need so it's reusable, so you can just call something like: Dim test as string = GetRemoteData(url, field)

Comment: I want to use Google Chrome open my webpages. I need to change wreqBeta.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5" How do I do this?